# Order of operations in sql for "inner join" and "where"

Tags: sql, join, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a query which looks like that

```
select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
                 inner join t3 on t2.c2 = t3.c2
                 inner join t4 on t3.c3 = t4.c3
                 where t3.c4 = value
```

I am interested to know what is the order of operations:

**(1)** all inner joins will be executed and after that the columns having `t3.c4 = value` will be selected

**(2)** instead of doing join with t3 the join will be actually done (first) with table having `t3.c4 = value`. I.e first the temp table with `t3.c4 = value` will be created (`t3tmp`) and after that all inner joins will be executed , just instead of `t3` `t3tmp` will be used

Comment: Logically, JOIN chains are executed from left to right, and after that the WHERE is applied. However, the dbms optimizer may chose a completely different order to execute the query.

Comment: please tag the DBMS you are using, since the answer can vary.

Comment: The SQL language is *designed* so that you tell the system *what to do* rather than *how to do it*, and it's then the job of the optimizer to work out how best to do that, what order to apply filters/joins/etc. If you want to know how a specific database engine handles this, please add a tag for that product, but be aware that the answer may very easily still be "it depends"

Answer (score 0):

Consider using either explain method on the DataFrame or looking at the Spark UI to gain more knowledge about how your specific case was optimized.

---

### Pushdown of transitive join predicate

<strike>Should be the second option as of Spark 1.6 (Though it will probably depend on the condition itself).</strike>

The t3.c4 condition will most likely be pushed into the t3 results before join.
More information on how Spark handles it is available in [SPARK-12532](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12532) Jira ticket and relevant [pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10490).

#### EDIT #1

It seems the change mentioned above were delayed, and was not merged into 1.6.

### Join Reordering

As for the order of joins, as far as I know, there is a plan to add a cost-based optimizer to actually plan the which join should go first, but it's not implemented yet.

At this time, I can find only this [SPARK-12602](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12602) Jira ticket, which mentioning the outer/inner join reordering (there were some other tickets as well for other cases).